# Responsive background image in React

Tags: reactjs, background-image, responsive, react-bootstrap

I have a `React` component that is being used as a home page for a site that I am building.

I am using `react-bootstrap` and I need to know how to create a responsive background image for this home page using `React`.

Answer (score 3):

For responsive image given `style={{height:'auto',width:'100%'}}`

Answer (score 1):

Use this ..It's really work..

1. Add this library

**import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';**

2.Import image though..

**import <*Image Name*> from ' <*Image path*>';**

3.for import image..

**<Image src={<*Image Name*>} fluid />**